# Security of password in a cron job on a VPS

Tags: security, cron, password, mysql

I have a site hosted on a VPS and need to run a MySQL dump nightly.  If I create the cron command:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword database | gzip > /path/to/zip/file
```

are there any security issues?  I'm aware of the `config.conf` possibility for not putting the username and password in the commnand, but if someone gets into my server, they'd be able to see both my cron jobs and the conf file so I'm not sure that I see any difference between the two.

Answer (score 1):

It may be unimportant in the cases you care about, but one difference
is that a properly-protected file (permissions `600`) will only be
readable to its owner (and root) while, on some Unix variants, the
entire command line of all commands are readable to all users of the
system using, for example, the command `ps`.

(As a contradiction to this, some commands that accept a password on
the command line will garble it so that it does not appear in ps's
output.)

So it may make a difference if an intruder gets onto our server as a different user from the one owning the configuration file.